# is this parallelism grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, parallelism

does this sentence make sense "*One of the reasons why spoken English teaching in China seems to be not really successful is **not only** because students lack of enthusiasm, **but** their teachers as well*" when it comes to parallelism?

Comment: You'll need to write either "... _because students **lack** enthusiasm, but their teachers **do** as well_" (verb) or "... _because **of** student**s'** lack of enthusiasm, but their teacher**s'** as well_" (noun possessed by students/teachers). Both would mean the same thing, in my opinion.

Comment: Could also be restructured as " because not only students, but their teachers as well, lack enthusiasm, "

Comment: @ Mary thanks! but when i'm writing i'll never use this structure as i tend to use rather colloquial language, like i'm writing a diary..

Comment: @ Kman3 thanks. my grammar's just not good enough.. i may practise more

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the sentence is poorly written. It would be more intelligible if you said

> One of the reasons why spoken English teaching in China *does not seem
> to be very successful* is because ***not only students lack*** enthusiasm,
> ***but their teachers (do) as well***.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also) explains that we can omit ***also*** in this structure:

> ***Not only … but also***
> We use not only X but also Y in formal contexts:
>
> The war caused *not only* destruction and death *but also* generations of
> hatred between the two communities.
>
> We can sometimes leave out ***also***:
>
> I identified with Denzel Washington *not only* as an actor *but* as a
> person.

***Also*** of course is a synonym of ***as well*** (and in the writing of the sentence the structure is ***not only... but... as well***), but as you can see in the comments they are not used in the same way.

[TheWordCounter](https://thewordcounter.com/blog-not-only-but-also/) shows that there are other variations:

> Variations on Not Only / But Also
> Sometimes the phrase “not only” can
> be replaced by “not alone” or “not just.” Similarly, “also,” “but
> too,” and but as well” can be good substitutes for “but also.”
>
> Not only was he strong, but he was smart as well.
>
> not just…but also
> not only…also
> not only…but too
> not only…but as well
> not alone…but also

With ***also*** your sentence would be:

> One of the reasons why spoken English teaching in China does not seem to be very successful is because ***not only students but also teachers*** lack enthusiasm.

Answer (score 0):

While using 'not only...but also', the nature of what follows immediately after 'not only' should match with that of 'but also'. Thus it may be rewritten as "One of the reasons why spoken English teaching in China seems to be not really successful is because of the lack of enthusiasm not only of students but also their teachers." But the sentence, I should tell, is too wordy.

Comment: thanks Ram, and concerning your comment hh i agree with you, that's been one of my writing problems, and I tried to write sth extra to meet the word requirement

Answer (score -1):

**"Reason"** and **"because"** cannot be used together. These are redundant.

*"The **reason** for my absence was **because of** my illness."*  This is incorrect.

Here, the correct sentence should be :

*" The reason for my absence was my illness."*
Or,
*"My absence was because of my illness (or, due to my illness)."*

Besides, **"the reasons why"** also seems to be redundant. It's better to say : **"the reasons for which"**...

Therefore, the correct version of your example is :

> *"One of the **reasons** for which spoken English teaching in China seems to be not really successful is the lack of enthusiasm not only of the students but also of their teachers."*

Or,

> *"Spoken English teaching in China seems to be not really successful **because of** the lack of enthusiasm not only of the students but also of their teachers."*

Comment: an easy mistake! thanks for pointing out!!

Comment: This is simply not true. They may be redundant depending on the context, but there is nothing incorrect about using reason and because in sequence.